# How can I resolve function-dependency loops in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk, circular-dependency

In my Lua code (using the Corona SDK), my issue essentially boils down to this:

```
local function foo()
    bar()
end

local function bar()
    foo()
end
```

However, because Lua is done line-by-line, this has no chance of working. Futhermore, I don't see a way to avoid this dependency loop; foo() creates DisplayObjects that call bar() for touch events, which itself has the capability of calling foo(). To put it another way, I need to be able to make buttons that, when clicked, make more buttons that can do the same thing.

Futhermore, I know Lua doesn't have function prototyping like in C/C++. Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that

```
local function FuncName() end
```

is syntactically equivalent to:

```
local FuncName = function() end
```

So it's a simple matter of declaring the local variables, but setting their function values *after* the declaration:

```
local foo = nil
local bar = nil

foo = function()
    bar()
end

bar = function()
    foo()
end
```

Comment: Also note that you can still use the `function foo () ... end` form: if `foo` was previously declared local (with `local foo`) it will create a local function, not a global one.